# Writing Better Milestone/Touchpoint Follow-Up Emails

Tags: communication, clients, milestones, email

I am a technical (software deployment) project manager. I regularly have clients request 15+ minute check-in calls, which I am happy to take. The calls are pre-scheduled and have no set agenda.

I take fairly robust notes in Microsoft OneNote, but they are not written for the client as much as for myself.

Sending follow-up emails that list action items for both the client and PM is critical, so I am wondering if any of you have best practices for putting together unambigious and actionable follow-up emails that can be sent within 20 minutes of a check-in call's conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

My technique to tackle this is fairly straight forward. I add an agenda item "Meeting summary and actions"

When meeting summary is talked about, I also type up a few bullet points and actions and send it out before closing the meeting.

Once meeting finishes, usually another meeting starts or get pulled into tasks. So doing this during the meeting could be an approach.